# Errores con GlassFish server - Java

Tags: java, web, servlets

estoy aprendiendo a usar servlets en java con el servidor GlassFish 5.0.1 y a la hora de compilar el proyecto, sale el siguiente error:

```
The module has not been deployed.
```

Y la solución encontrada fue poner un pass y user al servidor. Sin embargo, al compilar nuevamente, sale este error:

```
Could not start glassfish server: autorization failed for another server running on administrator port
```

Según las soluciones encontradas, había que chequear los servidores en el caso de que esté en marcha otro que no sea GlassFish (cosa que no pasó) y borrar el pass y user, los borré y quedé en la misma situación.

Answer (score 1):

Bien esto puede suceder cuando estás tratando de desplegar dos servidores con el mismo puerto. Puedes intentar dos cosas.
1: ve a la configuración de tu servidor y cambia el puerto por defecto, es decir, generalmente se usa el 80 pero podrías usar cualquier como el 8080 o el 8081.
2: si estas en windows entra en la consola y teclea netstat -oan. Esto te responderá con 5 columnas, a nosotros nos importa la dirección local y la columna PID. Identifica en la columna de Dirección local el puerto que estés usando y el PID que tiene. Luego tipea en consola task kill /PID numeroDelPID -F

Ejemplo:
taskkill /PID 5754 -F

y ya esto debería poder servirte.